# Should I use “with” or “of”?

Tags: prepositions, verbs

> This coffee is also available in packs **with** smaller amounts?

> This coffee is also available in packs **of** smaller amounts?

Which preposition should I use in the sentence above “of” or “with”? I thought a pack has an amount of something but I couldn’t decide whether I should use “with” or “of”. I gave such an example to understand which preposition should be used for the verb “have”.

Comment: Typically, we'd say large, medium or small packages, no preposition or smaller or larger packages. Packages of coffee, like to use at home or in a machine. Or packets.

Comment: @gonefishin'again. https://organicroastedcoffee.co.uk/how-to-store-coffee-to-keep-it-fresh/ package of coffee [unground beans] UK

Comment: @gonefishin'again. A bag of coffee, yes. A package of coffee, yes. A packet of coffee, yes. Personally, as a coffee drinker, I would never say a pack of coffee.

Comment: @gonefishin'again. The cherry picker is not me. I gave three possibilities, you initially, one. So....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Packs **of** smaller amounts" means the packs themselves are smaller, so they hold a smaller amount of the substance. They will likely be marked with a smaller number on the outside, like packs of 1 kg, 500 g, etc.

"Packs **with** smaller amounts" could mean the same as above, OR it could mean the *same sized packs, but having a smaller amount inside*.

Answer (score 2):

*Pack*, like many words in English, takes a particular kind of complement: in the case of *pack* an *of* phrase, designating the items constituting the pack. So *packs of smaller amounts* would be idiomatic.

You can use a *with* phrase with it, as you can with many nouns; but it has no special meaning relative to a "pack" - in particular, it would not normally be understood as specifying the things that the pack was made up of.

So *packs with smaller amounts* means something like "packs (of something unspecified) accompanied by, or using, smaller amounts". In this case, I guess the meaning would be the same, but I still it's not idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

> This coffee is also available in packs with/of smaller amounts

Both versions are so awkward that as a native I honestly don't know which might be technically right or wrong. You can count packs using 'of', but there would usually be a quantifier.
"You can buy these in packs of ten." etc.

No-one would really say it that way, unless they were counting, they'd just get the whole thing done with

> This coffee is also available in smaller packs.

Or, to give out full information, including the count, all in one shot

> This coffee is available in packs of 250g, 500g and 1Kg